# Using Regex inside for loop

Tags: rust

I'm learning Rust and trying to apply a regex inside for loop reading a line.

```
extern crate regex;
use regex::Regex;

use std::fs::File;
use std::io::{BufReader, Result, BufRead};

fn main() -> Result<()> { 
    let file = File::open("logs.log")?;
    let reader = BufReader::new(file);
    
    let re = Regex::new(r"^\w{3}\s{1,2}\d{1,2}\s(?:\d{2}:){2}\d{2}").unwrap();

    for line in reader.lines() {
        println!("{}", re.is_match(line));
    }

    Ok(())
}
```

**using cargo run I receive the error above**

```
  --> src/main.rs:14:36
   |
14 |         println!("{}", re.is_match(line));
   |                                    ^^^^ expected `&str`, found enum `std::result::Result`
   |
   = note: expected reference `&str`
                   found enum `std::result::Result<String, std::io::Error>`
```

**using rustc file.rs, receive this**

```
| extern crate regex;
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ can't find crate
```

is that the right way to applying regex ?

Comment: I don't think that the error is related to `regex`. `println!("{}", line.unwrap());` can fix this compiler error.

Comment: I forgot to mention `println!("{}", re.is_match(line));`

Comment: Could you update the error message aswell?

Comment: Sure, I updated the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[From the docs on `BufRead::lines`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.BufRead.html#method.lines):

> **The iterator returned from this function will yield instances of `io::Result<String>`.** Each string returned will not have a newline byte (the 0xA byte) or CRLF (0xD, 0xA bytes) at the end.

(emphasis mine)

Your `line` variable is a `Result<String>`, yet you try to call `re.is_match` on it like it's a string. Since your `main` function already returns a `Result`, the cleanest solution is to use the [`?` operator](https://doc.rust-lang.org/edition-guide/rust-2018/error-handling-and-panics/the-question-mark-operator-for-easier-error-handling.html) (pronounced "try operator") to return an `Err` whenever any `line` is an `Err`:

```rust
for line in reader.lines() {
    println!("{}", re.is_match(&line?));
}
```

You also need `&line` instead of `line`, since the function takes `&str`, not `String`.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're getting this error is because you haven't unwrapped the `line`, simply change your print line to

```rust
println!("{}", line.unwrap());
```

and it should work.

This error is unrelated to `regex`.

Answer (score 1):

You could also do this with a `filter_map` operation on the iterator. I am sure there is some way to reduce the number of operations here, but this is what I got...

```
extern crate regex;
use regex::Regex;

use std::fs::File;
use std::io::{BufRead, BufReader, Result};

fn main() -> Result<()> {
    let file = File::open("logs.log")?;
    let reader = BufReader::new(file);

    let re = Regex::new(r"^\w{3}\s{1,2}\d{1,2}\s(?:\d{2}:){2}\d{2}").unwrap();

    reader
        .lines()
        .filter_map(Result::ok)
        .filter(|line| re.is_match(line))
        .for_each(|line| println!("{}", line));

    Ok(())
}
```